# Javascript for-in global scope

Tags: javascript, object

I just had an embarrassing realization...

I regularly loop through objects as such:

```
for (item in results) {
  if (results.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    // do something with results[item];
  }
}
```

In a large application, I started getting odd leaks into the global namespace. I never suspected that `item` above floats into the global namespace as it was never declared. I guess it does?

Would the proper syntax be the following?

```
for (var item in results) {
  if (results.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    // do something with results[item];
  }
}
```

For some reason I seem to have missed this in examples.

#### EDIT

I am otherwise very firm about declaring all of my variables and don't let anything into the global namespace. For some reason I thought for...in loops were some special exception, but the more I think about it, the dumber that conclusion seems.

Comment: The snippets are equal, if you've declared `item` elsewhere in the first snippet. If `item` is global, you may expect troubles in IE, where it is a protected method name in `window`. Have you seen [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), `hasOwnProperty` is extremely slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; you need to declare your variables.

If you add `'use strict';` (which you should for all new code), you'll get an error when you forget to.

Comment: ++ for 'use strict'. I am going to start using that.

Comment: Because 'use strict' can change the way code behaves (throws error where it would not have in this case), you want to use it only for new code as @SLaks said. Beware if you have a javascript concatenation + minification process because your old code will change if 'use strict' is declared at the file level!  The workaround is to wrap your code in a giant function that has a 'use strict' to limit its scope that is friendly to concatenation.  The most common way of doing this is with a IIFE.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to statically analyze your JavaScript code for other possible problems.